# Bootstrap No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, model-view-controller, fonts, web-config

In my MVC site i have installed a bootstrap superhero theme that use the font-family 'Lato' from fonts.googleapis. 
The file bootstrap.superhero.css file contain this line... i think that the problem is here.

```
@import url("//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700");
```

I have included in web.config the code

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
  </system.webServer>
```

but the error is always present. 
What can i do for import correctly the font ?

Comment: try to use <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'> inside your head.

Comment: Not work ! 
Font from origin 'http://fonts.gstatic.com' has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:63415' is therefore not allowed access.

Answer (score 0):

There's no problem with the **link** tag. Modify your **htaccess** so that server could accept another origin's content.

```
<FilesMatch "\.(ttf|otf|eot|woff)$">
      <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
      </IfModule>
    </FilesMatch>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Where can i find this file ??

Comment: Find it in your root directory of site. If it's not there, create a new .htaccess file and paste the above code.